# XMLDeserialize to Object ISO-8859-1

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I am trying, unsuccessfully, to deserialize the following XML string returned from a third party service into a C# object collection:

```
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?><DataService><Request ID=\"2461627\" Status=\"Pending\"><TimeOffDate>2015-07-02</TimeOffDate><TimeStart></TimeStart><TimeEnd></TimeEnd><TimeOffHours>8.000</TimeOffHours><TimeOffTypeName>Holiday</TimeOffTypeName><LoginID>SPete</LoginID><Firstname>Stinky</Firstname><Lastname>Pete</Lastname><Comment><![CDATA[]]></Comment></Request><Request>...</Request></DataService>"
```

Here is my class definition:

```
    [XmlRoot]
public sealed class DataServiceModel {
    List<RequestModel> requests;

    [XmlArray("DataService"), XmlArrayItem("Request", Type = typeof(RequestModel))]
    public List<RequestModel> Requests { get { return requests ?? (requests = new List<RequestModel>()); } }

}

public class RequestModel {
    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("TimeOffDate")]
    public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("TimeStart")]
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("TimeEnd")]
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("TimeOffHours")]
    public decimal Hours { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("TimeOffTypeName")]
    public string TimeOffType { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("LoginID")]
    public string LoginId { get; set; }
}
```

And the code I am using to deserialize what's returned by the service I am calling:

```
        protected IEnumerable<RequestModel> ProcessResults(byte[] result) {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataServiceModel));
            var isoEncoder = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");                               
            var resultString = isoEncoder.GetString(result);
            using (var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(resultString))) {
                var dataServiceModel = (DataServiceModel)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
                return dataServiceModel.Requests;
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine until the last two lines of code to deserialize the XML string to the object where I get the exception message: "There is an error in XML document (1, 45)." which is at the start of the DataService tag.

The full exception message is this:

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>There is an error in XML document (1, 45).</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>...</StackTrace>
<InnerException>
    <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
    <ExceptionMessage><DataService xmlns=''> was not expected.</ExceptionMessage>
    <ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
    <StackTrace>at  Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderDataServiceModel.Read4_DataServiceModel()
    </StackTrace>
</InnerException>
```

Comment: you are missing the 'Comment' element. Can you post the full exception you are seeing?

Comment: I am not expecting to use the Comment element. Is it necessary to include?

Comment: You should have recieved an inner exception, don´t you?

Comment: Good catch. I wasn't looking for that. It was:
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage><DataService xmlns=''> was not expected.</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the following would work for me:

```
protected IEnumerable<Request> ProcessResults(byte[] result) {
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Request[]), new XmlRootAttribute("DataService") {Namespace = ""});
    var isoEncoder = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    var resultString = isoEncoder.GetString(result);
    using (var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(resultString))) {
        var requests = (Request[])serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        return requests;
    }
}
```

With the following modifications to the Model class:

```
public sealed class Request {
    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeOffDate { get; set; }
    public string TimeStart { get; set; }
    public string TimeEnd { get; set; }
    public decimal TimeOffHours { get; set; }
    public string TimeOffTypeName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string LoginID { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

This allowed me to remove the DataServiceModel class from the solution completely.

Comment: What should I do if I already have a string? I.e. my `result` is `string` and not `byte[]`.